# Python dictionary: Remove all the keys that begins with s

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dictionary like

```
dic = {'s_good': 23, 's_bad': 39, 'good_s': 34}
```

I want to remove all the keys that begins with 's_'

So in this case first two will be removed.

Is there any efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for k in dic.keys():
  if k.startswith('s_'):
    dic.pop(k)
```

Comment: darn. beat me to the answer - stachoverflow only lets me post one answer per 3 minutes

Comment: Not a good idea, in general, to mutate something you're iterating over -- and on Python 3, `keys` is a `dictview` not a list.

Comment: Python2 returns a copy of the dictionary keys which we iterate over so we are not changing the container. Python3 returns a dictview, a lazy sequence, that sees changes in the underlying dictionary so this will not work unless 'dic.keys()' is changed to 'list(dic.keys())'

Comment: why is this wrong ? 
`for k in dic:`  instead of `for k in dic.keys():`

Comment: I want revert my vote because in python 3 for key in parameters.keys(): 
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Answer (score 25):

```
for k in dic.keys():
    if k.startswith('s_'):
        del dic[k]
```

*** EDIT ***
now in python 3 , years after the original answer, `keys()` returns a view into the dict so you can't change the dict size.

One of the most elegant solutions is a copy of the keys:

```
for k in list(dic.keys()):
    if k.startswith('s_'):
        del dic[k]
```

Comment: but 'del' is the preferred way and it's faster. That is, "a={'x': 1}; a.pop('x')" takes 0.286 µsec per loop while "a={'x': 1}; del a['x']" takes only 0.178 µsec per loop.

Comment: Not only that, it is also semantically better. `del` tells that you wish to remove the entry while `pop` tells you wish to retreive it. So in this case I prefer del to pop. ;)

Comment: Nah, the most elegant solution is to create a new dict without those keys using a dict comprehension.

Comment: I admire the choice of dic and k as variables.

Answer (score 11):

With python 3 to avoid the error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

This should do it:

```
list_keys = list(dic.keys())
for k in list_keys:
  if k.startswith('s_'):
    dic.pop(k)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
dic = {k: v for k, v in dic.items() if not k.startswith("s_")}
```

Note that this creates a new dictionary (which you then assign back to the `dic` variable) rather than mutating the existing dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this:

```
dic = dict( [(x,y) for x,y in dic.items() if not x.startswith('s_')] )
```

Comment: That doesn't remove the keys from the dict. It creates a new dict without the keys, instead.

Comment: It's interesting that you felt the need to down vote in addition to supplying your own answer. I guess pedantism is alive and well, eh? I wonder (not having tested it) if removing from the existing list is actually *faster* that creating a new one. That was actually his primary question.

Comment: I haven't down voted you, but (1) @nosklo is correct (2) the word is "pedantry" (3) you omitted to mention that the code should differ between 2.x and 3.x (iteritems vs items) (4) the square brackets are redundant in modern Python (5) whether it is faster or not will be influenced by how many keys start with 's_'

Comment: @John Mahin: Actually, the word pedantism is correct, if a bit old fashioned, he said pedantically :-). It is a variant form of pedantry. Ref. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedantism and other online sources.